# Hibernate does not find Entity

Tags: hibernate, exception, entity

I am trying to create two simple Tables with a couple of records in a Postgresql database running a simple Java application and using Hibernate. I have created the entities `Employee` and `Department` as described in http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/ . I do not use Maven. My main method lying in the same package as the two Entities looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Department department = new Department();
    department.setDepartmentName("Sales");
    session.save(department);

    Employee emp1 = new Employee("Nina", "Mayers", "111");
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "222");

    emp1.setDepartment(department);
    emp2.setDepartment(department);

    session.save(emp1);
    session.save(emp2);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create-drop</property>
</session-factory>
```

After running the application, the following error comes up:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.al.hibernatetest.Department
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1063)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1433)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:205)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:190)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:91)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
at com.al.hibernatetest.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Due to unknown to me reason, the hibernate cannot recognize the entities? What could be the problem? Anything in the configuration? A missing jar? Anything in the creation of the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mapping class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.Department"/>
<mapping class="net.viralpatel.hibernate.Employee"
```

You forgot to copy these two lines in hibernate.cfg.xml.